# Can't import dbus in venv

Tags: python, import, dbus, python-venv

OS:Ubuntu 20
python: 3.8.2
IDE:Pycharm CE

Generally speaking, situation is that I can import dbus in terminal via /usr/bin/python3, but I have to init my project in pycharm and tried to build a venv, which is based on interpreter(/usr/bin/python3).

However, in pycharm's terminal(venv activated), I failed to import dbus.
But if I choose system interpreter directly without venv, everything is ok.

Already tried to copy dbus folder from system package root to venv but no effort.
Don't think reinstall dbus-python can resolve this problem because it works fine in real-envi, and I've installed dbus-python in venv already.

Just wondering why... cause it's still a little trouble without venv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a requirement with dbus-python to create the Python virtual environment with the `--system-site-packages` because it is dependent on packages installed with a system package manager.

In Pycharm it means checking the `Inherit global site-packages` box when creating the virtual environment.

You could look at using a different Python D-Bus binding that don't have the same dependency such as [pydbus](https://pypi.org/project/pydbus/).